# MotionPro Ubuntu Client Configuration error, using Windows 10 MotionPro profile, trying to connect to Win10 PC

Tags: vpn, windows-10, remote-desktop

I am trying to remotely log into my work Windows 10 PC using MotionPro. I already have it configure on another Windows 10 laptop, so I just exported the profile and imported it into the MotionPro client on Ubuntu. However, I am unable to connect as it throws the following error. It seems to be working fine from a Windows 10 PC/Laptop trying to connect to my work's Windows 10 PC. What am I missing?

```
The MotionPro client fails to obtain the configurations of L3VPN. Please check you virtual site configuration or network connection.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10